# readHexInteger from java to nodejs

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, hex, decimal

Got this code in java :

```
public static int readHexInteger(ChannelBuffer buf, int length) {

    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        int b = buf.readUnsignedByte();
        result *= 10;
        result += b >>> 4;
        result *= 10;
        result += b & 0x0f;
    }

    if (length % 2 == 1) {
        int b = buf.getUnsignedByte(buf.readerIndex());
        result *= 10;
        result += b >>> 4;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to code the same thing but with nodejs.

Is there any java/nodejs hacker in the room ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So, did you try anything?

Comment: why do you need nodejs? can not you use just javascript?

Comment: I don't have any skill for low level stuffs like that and in java. With nodeJS, there are Buffer related functions :

readUInt8, readUInt16LE, readUInt16BE, readUInt32LE, readUInt32BE. 

I tried to test each functions one by one without success. I didn't found equivalent of "buf.getUnsignedByte(buf.readerIndex());" with nodejs.

Right now, i'm testing js code without understand exactly what i am doing.Got a raw packet and the result of the 10 bytes after the first byte as reference. Trying to convert https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/commit/a3441d3bcd02ec48e408957dfdc61dc6850bc339 in nodejs.

Comment: @user3200809 any js or nodejs solution will be welcome !